# Replacing blank cells with text in a specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I have been attempting to patch together VBA fragments to create a macro to do the following:

I must replace all blank cells within the active range with the word 'UNREPORTED'.  The range covers Columns C through L. Row 1 is the Column Headers, so it needs to effect Row 2 through the last active row.  The spreadsheet covers columns A to U, so I do not want to define all the way to the left or the right.  Column C will have no blank cells, so it may be useful for defining the active rows.  All other Columns could have a blank row at the bottom.

Comment: Learning VBA is a great step - this is a relatively easy thing as well.  I recommend using the Macro Recorder to record a find/replace.  Start the macro recorder, select your range, then do Find/Replace.  You'll leave the find field blank, and in the "Replace" field, put "UNREPORTED" and hit ENTER or Replace All. That will create a macro that you can look at and see if you understand what it's doing.  If you still don't, post what you've tried (and any code) in your post. SO isn't a code writing service, but we're happy to help guide you if you let us know what you've tried, and post any code.

Comment: Thanks, @BruceWayne.  I tried recording a Find/Replace, but I couldn't figure out how to change the code to extend to the last active cell, instead of the specific last cell I selected.  I will run this macro on a weekly report, which has a varying number of rows, so that flexibility is crucial.

Comment: If you post what the macro recorder did (thus showing us what you've tried), we could probably take a look and tweak to do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could help, remember to change the name of the sheet. And preferably save the macro in a Module

```
Sub macro()
Dim i As Double
Dim j As Integer
Dim ActiveRows As Double

For i = 1 To 1000000
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 3).Value <> "" Then
        ActiveRows = ActiveRows + 1
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 1 To ActiveRows
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j + 1, i + 2) = "" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j + 1, i + 2) = "UNREPORTED"
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```